# ARCH+GARCH terms larger than 1

Tags: garch, arch

I understand that if the sum of ARCH and GARCH terms are larger than one, it would mean that the variance is exponentially increasing over time. Not desirable phenomenon. But what Is done about this? In my case, this happens at GARCH(1,1).

Comment: If the sum is equal to one then this is IGARCH(1,1) model.

Comment: You could try restricting the GARCH coefficients to sum to less than one when fitting the model. There is an option `fit.control=list(stationarity=1)` in `ugarchfit` function in "rugarch" package in R.

Comment: Please Richard Hardy , how we can reduce the sum of ARCH and Terme , in Eviews .tHANK S ?